# Passing an url hash through location.assign()

Tags: javascript

I want to pass a parameter to a new page through the url hash :

```
location.assign = 'display.php' + '#test';
```

However, the hash doesn't show up in the new `display.php` page.
I tried location.hash(), but it only changes the hash for the current page (`home.php`) and not for `display.php`.

I don't know if that's useful but i'm working with Wamp.
So the final url looks like `http://localhost/tests/home.php`.

Comment: should it be `location.assign('display.php' + '#test');`?

Comment: No, the result appears to be the same (the hash still doesn't appear)

Comment: why not use `location.href = 'display.php#test'` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[location.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign) is a method, not a property.  And therefore, should be invoked like this:

```
location.assign('display.php#test');
```

Based on the documentation, this should respect the entire url (with anchors).

You may want to use `location.href` instead to set the location:

```
location.href = 'display.php#test';
```

This is often the idiomatic way to redirect the browser from JavaScript.